# How to type dispatch of an async thunk?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-hooks, redux-thunk

I am currently using reduxjs/toolkit and I am having trouble typing my hooks to return a dispatch of an async thunk. Here is my setup following https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/usage-with-typescript (not fully functional code):

```
// thunk.ts

export const callThunk: AsyncThunk<
  ResponseBody,
  void,
  {state: RootState}
> = createAsyncThunk(
  'someAsyncThunkAction',
  async (_data, {rejectWithValue}) => {
   
      const response = await someAPICall();
      if (!response.ok) {
        return rejectWithValue(`Put failed: ${response.status}`);
      } else {
        return await response.json();
      }
);
```

```
// store.ts

export const store = configureStore({reducer: rootReducer});

export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch;
export const useAppDispatch = () => useDispatch<AppDispatch>();
```

```
// hook.ts
import {callThunk} from './thunk'
import {useAppDispatch} from './store'

type HookProperties = {
  onCallThunk: () => // <--- this is the type that I haven't figured out
};
export const useHook = (): HookProperties => {
  const appDispatch = useAppDispatch();

  return {
    onCallThunk: () => appDispatch(callThunk())
  };
};
```

and hopefully I can call this hook in my component as follow:

```
import {useHook} from './hook'

const {onCallThunk} = useHook();

onCallThunk().then(/* do something here */)
```

What should the type of `onCallThunk` be in  `hook.ts`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet here would be: either the part of it *you expect to be used*, so something like

```
type HookProperties = {
  onCallThunk: () => void // for example if you don't care about the result being used
};
```

or, simply: leave the `: HookProperties` annotation away and leave it at that. TypeScript knows the return type better than you could write it on your own and you gain nothing by manually writing that down - except for more maintenance later on when you change something.